# Skype url scheme not working to redirecting to particular user chat screen

Tags: ios, swift, skype, url-scheme

I am using below url scheme for redirect to particular users chat screen

**skype://UserId?chat**

Before skype new version it was working perfect but now after new release of skype its stop working

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx#chats):-

```
skype:skype.test.user.1?chat
```

Above syntax breakup:-

```
skype:participant1?chat[&topic=topicString]
```

Comment: Have already tried that but its open Create New group even i have skype contact chat.

Comment: You might have more luck cross posting this in their support queue assuming it exists, then adding the answer details into this answer.

Comment: @EvanAnger Just got to know. With the recent redesign of the Skype for iOS client, URIs are not currently supported on the Skype for iOS 5.x branch. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885(v=office.15).aspx